# How do you track new papers in journals

Tags: publications, journals

I am interested in the field of combinatorics and I would like to track new papers in journals on combinatorics (mainly the top of this list http://www.scimagojr.com/journalrank.php?category=2607).

How should I do that? For example, Journal on Graph Theory has email alert service but with some of the others I do not see such option.

How do you, personally, track new papers in your area?

Comment: Most major publishers still have RSS feeds, as far as I know. I have several set up for my preferred journals.

Comment: I'm really wondering why you need to do this.  Research in mathematics is not that time sensitive.  If, three or four times a year, you look at the website of each of the journals and check what's new, that's already more than frequent enough.  Frankly, I find that the vast majority of the papers I find professionally interesting I hear about by word-of-mouth, and browsing journals (or the ArXiv) is, professionally speaking, a waste of time.  In fact, I learn more looking at the websites of a few seminars than from browsing journals.

Comment: Side note: Scimago seems quite bad at classifying journals. Many of the first listed journals have as far as I know little to no relevance to combinatorics (e.g. "Discrete and Continuous Dynamical Systems", "Groups, Geometry and Dynamics")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try setting up one or more [GoogleScholar alerts](https://scholar.google.com/intl/en/scholar/help.html#alerts). You will get a mail if a new paper from your area of interest is added to Scholar. So please keep in mind that this only works for papers that do end up on scholar.

The alerts are not specific to any journal, but you can specify a set of keyword to search for. If you do not find another way this might be a workaround if you put some time into crafting your alerts. I use this to keep track of a very small but specific field (in Computer Sciences), so I do not know how it will scale up for your problem.

As far as I know it is not possible to set an alert a specific journal, but I have not put much research into this. It might be possible.

Comment: Note that this gives you alerts for newly added material, which may be a few years old by the time GS picks it up, rather than only new papers. It's not a major issue to skip over them, though. .

Answer (score 3):

Most journals have an RSS feed.  Use an RSS feed reader/aggregator (I currently use [Inoreader](http://www.inoreader.com/)) and subscribe to the feeds of the journals that interest you.

For example, the [Journal of Graph Theory's feed](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/rss/journal/10.1002/(ISSN)1097-0118) is linked from its homepage.

Comment: Is it possible to add RSS feed of special subjects? e.g. RSS of j. diff.geo with banach spaces keywords or something similar?